# Installing RHC package Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, openshift, apt

I just installed Elementary OS on my laptop which has the `apt-get` package management system, like Ubuntu.

I need to install `RHC` client tools on the laptop, but when I run

`sudo apt-get install rhc`

I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rhc
```

On researching online some suggested I run the command:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Which I did and get the following details:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Any idea why I can't install this basic software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**. Try installing it as a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rhc/versions/1.38.4).

There's [no `rhc` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=rhc) for trusty, a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release upon which Elementary OS is built.

`rhc` package is only available for wily, xenial or yakkety versions of Ubuntu (see top right corner of [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/rhc)).

OpenShift [official install documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/debian-ubuntu.html#client-tools) mistakenly states that `rhc` is available starting Ubuntu vivid release, but clicking that link leads to a non-existent page.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install gem`, and it says `gem is already the newest version`. However, when I try `gem install rhc` it says `the program 'gem' can be found in the following packages: * ruby * rubygems`

Comment: Hi Greg, that could be since you're installing the `gem` program using super user (aka `root`) via `sudo`, while executing the `gem` command under your current user. To quickly resolve this, try running `sudo gem install rhc`. 

However I'd recommend you install ruby via `rbenv` or `rvm` to make it possible installing / operating gems without the need of super user.

Comment: I then get error `sudo: gem: command not found`. This is weird. Thanks for the help btw